# The missing ingredient

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Using the starter and main course as examples, fill in the menu by adding the type of beverage required for the dessert.

> **Starter**
>   Peebles goat cheese and Vietnamese bread in the manner of Machiavelli
>
> **Main course**
>   Paraguayan artist Joan Castro’s sugar-coated shark dish
>
> **Dessert**
>   Childlike author Charlotte Hitler’s sour herring and [*alcoholic beverage*]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: in what country do peebles count as an ingredient?

Comment: Peebles is a town in Scotland.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan But then the starters have only one ingredient, unlike all the other lines.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier but they all contain two proper names.

Comment: You guys weren't confused enough yet, so I went ahead and added a few words on each line to throw you off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We might, for instance, serve

> Spätlese wine

with the dessert.

Starter:

> Peebles [Na P**ù**ballan] goat cheese [ch**è**vre] and Vietnamese bread [Bánh m**ì**] in the manner of [**à** la] Machiavelli [Niccol**ò**]

Main course:

> Paraguayan [Guaran**í**] artist Joan [Mir**ó**] Castro’s [Ra**ú**l] sugar-coated [glac**é**] shark dish [Kæstur h**á**karl].

Dessert:

> Childlike [na**ï**ve] author Charlotte [Bront**ë**] Hitler’s [F**ü**hrer] sour herring [Surstr**ö**mming] and ...

Notice that

> each course has one of each vowel suitably accented -- but the original version of the puzzle had fewer items on each line, so I'm not sure whether that's explicitly intended to be a constraint or not. Either way, my answer respects the constraint.

Credit where due:

> NudgeNudge spotted Guaran**í**. Fillet spotted Ra**ú**l. Thanks! (Reader, if you liked this answer, consider finding something of theirs and voting it up.)

Comment: Wow, great job! Maybe rot13(cnenthnlna vf thnenaí, juvyr negvfg Wbna vf Zveó nf lbh fnvq). Also rot13(pbhyq Uvgyre or Süuere? Naq abg Svqry ohg uvf oebgure Enúy?).

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer to reflect the second part of that, having noticed my inability to count to five; hadn't thought of the first half, though.

Comment: What about (rot13) svqry'f oebgure for Castro?

Comment: Duh, of course. Also, I just noticed I failed to credit NudgeNudge appropriately in my last edit. Fixing things now.

Comment: Great job. However, I confirm that glacé does mean coated or topped with sugar (or something else, chocolate, gianduja, etc.)

Comment: OK, I've removed my complaint about the meaning of "glacé".